# Convert Autocad DWG to OBJ, FBX or similar

Tags: 3d, file-format

I know this is only partially game development related, but couldnt find another place to ask.

How can i convert an autocad dwg or dxf file to a more 'common' format like OBJ, FBX, 3DS, etc. ?

i tried directly using autocad LT but the export options dont have any other format.s

free and oss solutions preferred.

Comment: You might consider trying Blender as in interchange for import/export. I know it exports FBX, with the right script (I think it's called OgreFBX or something like that). Also see http://www.blender3darchitect.com/2009/04/blender-3d-importing-dwg-files/

Comment: +1 to get you back up to zero (if you are the first to downvote, post a comment about it!)

Comment: What kind of software do you have access to? 3dstudiomax might do the trick.

Comment: i have access to the full range of autodesk products including 3dsmax, maya, autocad

Comment: I'm facing the same concern. 3DSOUT command has been removed since AutoCAD 2009 or 2010.
No way to use previous xxxout commands (bmpout, wmfout, 3dsout, etc.) I used to simply save dwg and link it to 3DS MAX, but this time, my file got "infected" by some undesireable data (that I couldn't get rid of.) which prevents MAX from reading the file (with err msg). Still seeking for an answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [3DSOUT](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/downloads/caas/downloads/content/autodesk-3dsout-command.html)

1. At the command prompt, enter 3dsout.
2. Select objects in the drawing to export.
3. Press ENTER.
4. In the 3D Studio Output File dialog box, in the File Name field,
   enter a file name.
5. Click Save.
6. In the 3D Studio File Export Options dialog box, select or change
   the necessary options. (See the [3DSOUT Reference](http://knowledge.autodesk.com/sites/default/files/file_downloads/readme_3dsout.html#3DSOUTReference) below for more
   information about these options.)
7. Click OK.

Comment: thanks but my autocad says: Command: 3DSout
Unknown command "3DSOUT".

Comment: is there a special way to install this tool? i just copied the two files into the autocad directory.

Comment: it's an command line application you don't need to install it , simply copy it to a directory go to cmd , go to 3dsout directory and use command , for example copy files in `c:\3dsout` go to cmd , type `cd c:\3dsout` then use above steps

Comment: is it a windows-command line application or an autocad command line application? the file ending is not .exe so i dont know how tot start that via cmd?

Comment: `3dsout64bit_enu.exe` is an installer/archive that you unpack to autocad... it is an *autocad command*